# Vertical-align play button with mobile navbar-button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to vertical-align and align="right" the play button with the button of the navbar menu - the one with the three bars. You can view the site here m.vtxfactory.org - try viewing with a lower resolution.

Here is the code I used for a temporary solution but it doesn't scale as it should when I try viewing the site in different resolutions.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="z-index: 1000000000000000000;background-color: #000;position: fixed;width: 100%;">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button style="margin-right: 15px;z-index: 1000000000000000000000000000" type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
          </button>
          <a href="#topp1" id="anchor0" class="anchorLink"><img src=images/vtxfactorylogo.png style="margin:8px;padding-left:-5px;max-width:50%;max-height:80px;" alt="main logo of website, vtx factory, vtxfactory.org, vtxfactory, business solutions, web design, audio production, 3d rendering, web development, html, css, javascript, jquery, web hosting, design, view more graphic, view more design, graphic design, digital, agency"></a>
    <div class="align-middle col-sm-2" style="color: #fff;position: absolute;top:17%;right:7vw;">
    <audio id=myAudio></audio>
    <audio id=peaks-audio preload=auto>Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
    <button style="background-color: #000" id=idj-play-button onclick=StartOrStop() class="btn btn-lg"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i>
    </button>
    <button style="background-color: #000" id=idj-pause-button onclick=StartOrStop() class="btn btn-lg hide"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
    </button>
    </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a style="font-size: 6vw;line-height:6vw;" href="#topp1" id="anchor1" class="anchorLink">Home</a></li>
            <li><a style="font-size: 6vw;line-height:6vw;" href="#featuress1" id="anchor2" class="anchorLink">Features and Plans</a></li>
            <li><a style="font-size: 6vw;line-height:6vw;" href="#newsletterr1" id="anchor3" class="anchorLink">Newsletter</a></li>
            <li><a style="font-size: 6vw;line-height:6vw;" href="#testimonialss1" id="anchor4" class="anchorLink">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a style="font-size: 6vw;line-height:6vw;" href="#contactss1" id="anchor5" class="anchorLink">Contacts</a></li>
            <li><a style="font-size: 6vw;line-height:6vw;" href="/policy/" target="_blank" id="anchor6" class="anchorLink">Policy</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: May I suggest looking at some Bootstrap Navbar examples? They might give you some idea. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/#navbars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry, but you need to cleanup your code and put all the inline CSS, please ensure that bootstrap navbar is similar to the standard bootstrap navbar in the [Bootstrap 3 Navbar Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar), now coming to your question, I checked your website, can you please add the below class to the play button.

```
.vert-center{
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right:7vw;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

**Before:**

```
<div class="align-middle col-sm-2" style="color: #fff;position: absolute;top: 50%;right:7vw;transform: translateY(-50%);">
<audio id="myAudio"></audio>
<audio id="peaks-audio" preload="auto">Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
```

**After:**

```
<div class="vert-center col-sm-2">
<audio id="myAudio"></audio>
<audio id="peaks-audio" preload="auto">Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
```

Please let me know if this class resolves your issue!

Comment: Perfect, this resolved my issue. But I have another problem, if I toggle the menu button, the play button will go along with it (hope I explained right?) Thanks once again.

Comment: @Rui Can you try the CSS ` @media(max-width:768px) { .navbar-header{position:relative} } `! Killer songs, actually enjoyed testing the website!

Answer (score 1):

Try using flex instead. It is a lot easier to align elements vertically using flex. Check out the code below.

```html
<div class="navbar-header" style="
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
">
      <button style="order: 3;margin-right: 15px;z-index: 1000000000000000000000000000;" type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a href="#topp1" id="anchor0" class="anchorLink" style="
    order: 1;
"><img src="images/vtxfactorylogo.png" style="margin:8px;padding-left:-5px;max-width:50%;max-height:80px;" alt="main logo of website, vtx factory, vtxfactory.org, vtxfactory, business solutions, web design, audio production, 3d rendering, web development, html, css, javascript, jquery, web hosting, design, view more graphic, view more design, graphic design, digital, agency"></a>
<div class="align-middle col-sm-2" style="color: #fff;/* position: absolute; *//* top:17%; *//* right:7vw; */order: 2;">
<audio id="myAudio"></audio>
<audio id="peaks-audio" preload="auto">Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>
<button style="background-color: #000" id="idj-play-button" onclick="StartOrStop()" class="btn btn-lg"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></i>
</button>
<button style="background-color: #000" id="idj-pause-button" onclick="StartOrStop()" class="btn btn-lg hide"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
</button>
</div>
    </div>
```

Just paste the code above into your site header.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to comment on your specific code other than saying that your `z-index`es made me LOL... and you should really consider some general housekeeping.

Anyway... you can perfectly center one element inside another using `position: absolute` on the element itself and anything except `static` on the parent that you want to center inside - the trick is to put the child at 50% from the top and then `translate` it 50% up:

```css
.offset_parent {
  height: 120px; /* doesn't matter how high it is */
  position: relative; /* anything but static */
  background: green;
}
.v_center {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="offset_parent">
  <div class="v_center">Always perfectly in the middle</div>
</div>
```

The reason this works is because `translate` (and `translateX` / `translateY`) is calculated relative to the childs size, while the `top` (and other position properties) is relative to the parents height.

If your element has a fixed height you can get better backwards compatibility by using a negative `margin-top` instead of `translate` (extremely outdated browsers may not support `transform`):

```css
.offset_parent {
  height: 120px; /* doesn't matter how high it is */
  position: relative; /* anything but static */
  background: green;
}
.v_center {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="offset_parent">
  <div class="v_center">Always perfectly in the middle</div>
</div>
```